# Нужно сделать анимацию, чтобы элементы прокручивались влево и появлялись справа (без пустоты, картинки всегда движутся друг за другом)

Tags: reactjs, анимация, css-animation, scss

*Для справки. Использую Next.js 13.5.4, React 18, SASS 1.69.7.*

Данный скрин сделан при разрешении 1920x1080. При более низких разрешениях пустота пропадает, но анимация все равно разрывается в конце. Либо же не доходит до конца и начинается заново.
В общем нужно сделать так, чтоб независимо от разрешения элементы шли друг за другом без огромной пустоты в конце.
[image: вот начало движения, он немного раньше конечно начиается, но в начале пустота меня не волнует]
[image: а вот уже под конец, когда я ожидаю чтоб появился 1й и 2й элемент, их нету, последний элемент доходит почти до-конца значок(nginx) и затем анимация резко начинается с нуля]

```js
const Slider = () => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.rootWrapperSlider}>
            {
                icons.map((icons)=>{
                  return   <Image key={icons.item} className={styles.ImageSlider} src={icons.item} />
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
};
```

```css
@keyframes slide {
  from {
    left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    left: -100%;
  }
}
.rootWrapperSlider {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  height: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ImageSlider {
  width: 123px;
  height: 123px;
  margin-left:6%;
  position: relative;
  animation: slide 15s linear infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.rootWrapperSlider {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  height: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ImageSlider {
  width: 123px;
  height: 123px;
  margin-left:6%;
  position: relative;
  animation: slide 15s linear infinite;
}
```

Вместо использования свойств `left`, лучше использовать `transform: translateX()` для перемещения элементов, чтобы они перемещались влево и появлялись справа.